# Shopify Customer's Order Page keeps redirecting back account page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am developing a Shopify theme. But when I want to navigate to customer's order pages, but I keep getting redirected back to the account page. Here is the link https://website.myshopify.com/account/orders.

My order.liquid is placed under the customers folder in theme template folder.

Does anyone knows whats causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [customers accounts are enabled](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/customer-accounts) on your store.